# Add GitHub libraries in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, github

I want to add [MathView](https://github.com/jianzhongli/MathView) in my project but it gives me an error. It says that it's not an existing version. Okay, Then I tried [other](https://github.com/judemanutd/KatexView) library. But this one gives me an error too. It says: "Could not resolve all files for configuration". I think I have to add something to work with GitHub libraries. I did some research but all of the posts are very old and outdated. Can you guys help me add those libraries in my project.

Answer (score 0):

implementation 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'

import this as (compile is deprecated).

Note. gradle has two files 1.build(project.PROJECTNAME)

```
                        2. build(module.PROJECTNAME.app)
```

inside 2. -> find dependencies{} ->
copy the implementation 'io.github.kexanie.library:MathView:0.0.6'
and sync you are good to go.

Comment: Yeah I know that much! It gives errors after sync